# proving divergence of a sequence $a_n=(-1)^nn-(-1)^nn^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help with this problem. We have to prove if the following sequence is divergent  $a_n=(-1)^nn-(-1)^nn^2 , n ∈ N$

Well now the problem is that i don't know how to prove it

Comment: Do you mean $a_n = n(-1)^n - n^2(-1)^n$ ?

Comment: yes please how should i prove that its divergent?

Comment: Try calculating the successive differences. They should get smaller for a convergent series (... which is a necessary, but *not* sufficient condition).

Comment: this is the problem I cant reduce/ simplify the sequence which should mean that its divergent but we have to show/prove that the sequence is divergent

Comment: Can you explain what a divergent sequence is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Theorem that says that if a sequence $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent, then every subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent. This means that if we can find a subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty}\subseteq (a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that is divergent, then the original sequence $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is divergent. Consider the subsequence $(a_{2m})_{m=1}^{\infty}\subseteq (a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$. For every $m\in\mathbb{N}$,

\begin{align*}
a_{2m}=(-1)^{2m}(2m)-(-1)^{2m}(2m)^{2}=2m-4m^{2}=2m(1-2m)\to-\infty
\end{align*}

so that the original sequence $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

It is $$(-1)^n(n(1-n))$$ and it is $$-n(n-1)$$ if $n$ is even and $$-n(1-n)=n(n-1)$$ if $n$ is odd. In the first case it tends to $-\infty$ and in the second one it tends to $+\infty$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

Suppose two sequence $$p_n = a_{2n}, \quad q_n = a_{2n-1}$$

Then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (2n - (2n)^2)=-\infty \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (-(2n-1) + (2n-1)^2) = \infty$$